# SQL - How to create a trigger for two joined tables which is used for inserting

Tags: sql, oracle, view, triggers

Ok , so I know that inserting information in a **view** based on two **joined tables** is impossible.

In order to do so , I need to create a trigger to insert the information in both tables , when an insert is made in that view.

For example :

```
CREATE VIEW myJoinedView AS
SELECT name,g.value from students
JOIN grades g on g.id=students.id;
```

The trigger is not working :

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON myJoinedView
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO students
    (name,value)
    SELECT i.myJoinedView
    FROM inserted i 
    INNER JOIN grades
    ON i.id = grades.id 
END myTrigger;
```

Then I'm trying to insert :

```
INSERT INTO myJoinedView VALUES ('Alex',10);
```

I don't know if the syntax is correct , I did not find any helpful documentation on this specific type of trigger.

I'm getting this error:

> Error(10,46): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when
>   expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception
>   exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update
>   while with     
>    << continue close current delete fetch lock
>   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge
>   pipe purge

Any help will be well received.
Thank you!

Comment: Let's take a step back.  What do you want to happen when you run this `insert` statement?  Do you always want to insert a new row in the `students` table?  Is `name` the primary key of `students`?  Or is `id` the primary key?  If you are inserting a new row, how do you populate the new value for `id`?  Is there a  sequence?  Or do you want to insert a new row in `students` only if there isn't a row with a matching `name`?  Presumably, you can have multiple students named "Alex" and each of those students can have multiple grades...

Comment: id is the primary key for both tables ; and no i just want to create a new row for every one of them like: In the students table i will have a new name Alex , and in grades i will have Alex' grade; yes i presume i've made a mistake i should have inserted id as well but still I don't see how would I solve this

Comment: OK.  So each student can have only one grade?  That seems odd from a business standpoint but OK.  How does the trigger know what `id` value to use?  Is there a sequence somewhere that it can call `nextval` on to get the new primary key value?  Are there any other columns in either table that need to be populated?

Comment: No,not really. Hmm based on your observations , an id must be inserted as well ; from my code no, the trigger does not know which id value to use; and looking at my constraints no , I don't think anymore columns should be populated except : id,students.name,grades.value

Comment: Then your view would need to `select` the `id` value as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either perform the inserts separately with separate single table insert or merge statements or by using a multi table insert (`insert all`) statement.  Assuming you have a sequence to generate the id you are joining on for example this code will work in a very rudimentary way, but has some significant issues:

```
create table students ( id number primary key
                      , name varchar2(60));

create table grades( id number not null
                   , value number
                   , constraint grades_fk1 foreign key (id) references students(id));

create sequence student_id_seq;

create or replace view studentgrades as
select name, value from students s join grades g on s.id = g.id;

create or replace trigger studentgrades_ii_trg 
instead of insert on studentgrades
begin
  insert all into students(id, name) values (student_id_seq.nextval, name)
             into grades(id, value) values (student_id_seq.nextval, value)
      select :new.name name, :new.value value from dual;
end;
/

insert into studentgrades values ('Alex',10);
insert into studentgrades values ('Alex',8);
```

The **BIG** issue with the above trigger is that every time a grade is inserted for 'Alex' a new student record for 'Alex' is also created instead of reusing the previous student record for 'Alex'.  That's probably not the desired behavior.  Instead it should probably just insert a new grade record for Alex.  One way to acheive this is for the studentgrades view to include the id column from the students table so you can uniquely identify which student to add the grade to, updating the trigger as needed:

```
create or replace view studentgrades as
select s.id, name, value from students s join grades g on s.id = g.id;

create or replace trigger studentgrades_ii_trg 
instead of insert on studentgrades
declare
  newid students.id%type;
begin
  if :new.id is null then
    newid := student_id_seq.nextval;
  else
    newid := :new.id;
  end if;
  insert all when :new.id is null
             then into students(id, name) values (id, name)
             else into grades(id, value) values (id, value)
      select newid id, :new.name name, :new.value value from dual;
end;
/

insert into studentgrades values (null, 'Paul',10);
insert into studentgrades values (student_id_seq.currval, 'Paul',8);
```

However, now what happens if you try this:

```
insert into studentgrades values (student_id_seq.currval, 'Mary',10);
```

In this case the name is effectively ignored and Paul gets a new grade so again this isn't quite right.  The question is should Paul's name be updated to Mary, or should a new student record for Mary be created, or should an exception be raised?